# NSNumberFormatter not displaying rupee symbol only on ipad device

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I am using an NSNumberFormatter with NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle to display in app purchas prices in my universal iOS app. My location is India, and the formatter correctly displays the indian rupee symbol in most devices I tested (ipad simulator, ipad 3 device, iphone 3gs device, iphone 4 device). However, only on the ipad first generation (running iOS 5.1.1), it displays a square instead of the rupee symbol.

All devices are running the latest ios that they support (iOS 6.0.1 on ipad 3, iphone 4 and iphone 3gs; iOS 5.1.1 on iPad 1).

The function we use to format the currency is:

```
@implementation SKProduct (LocalizedPrice)

- (NSString *)localizedPrice
{
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:self.priceLocale];
    NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:self.price];
    [numberFormatter release];
    return formattedString;
}

@end
```

Update1: This seems to happen only on iOS 5.1 and not on iOS 6.0 - I tried running on ipad simulator on ios 6 and on ios 5.1 - it works on ios 6 simulator but not on ios 5.1. Is there a way to display the currency symbol on ios 5.1?

Update2: For now, I check for OS version and display the symbol only in >= 6.0. This is what some of the other apps out there seem to be doing.

Thanks
Anand

Comment: Um, I don't think original iPads can run iOS 6...

Comment: Thanks @DaveDeLong - ipad 1 has 5.1.1. I have updated it above.

Comment: Thanks, @H2CO3. I added the relevant code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't working on a specific version of iOS or device you should file a radar.

[Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com)

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing this?

[image]

That's the "generic currency sign", which is what is used when the formatter doesn't have a specific known symbol to use.

It seems odd to me that your `NSNumberFormatter` on iOS 5.1 wouldn't have the Rupee symbol, because that's a fairly standard symbol.  But if that is indeed the case (and I'm sorry, I don't have an iOS 5.1 device here to check), you could do a find-and-replace in the formatted string to replace the generic currency symbol with the Rupee symbol.